# Django model formset displaying db data instead of empty formset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, formset

I'm using a model formset to allow a user to dynamically add duplicate forms to a table(modbus registers since a device can have multiple registers).

The problem I'm having is that as soon as I save the formset(store to db), when I come back to the same page to create a new device with registers, django renders all the previously created forms instead only 1 empty form(then being able to add forms to that).

Here is an example after having created 3 forms in my formset(stored in db):
[image]

Here is what it should look like:
[image]

It should only display 1 empty form in my formset, the user can then dynamically add forms.

my view:

```
def create_modbus_view(request):
    modbus_device = CreateModbusForm()
    RegisterFormset = modelformset_factory(Register, form=ModbusRegistersForm)
    register_forms = RegisterFormset()

    return render(
        request,
        'app/create_modbus.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'Create Modbus Device',
            'tag': 'create_modbus',
            'modbus_device': modbus_device,
            'register_forms': register_forms
        })
    )
```

models:

```
class Register(models.Model):
    ixRegister = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sRegisterName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    iStartingAddr = models.IntegerField()
    bRange = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ixRegisterType = models.ForeignKey(RegisterType)
    iOffset = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TRegister'

class ModbusDevice(models.Model):
    ixModbusDevice = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sModbusName = models.CharField(verbose_name='Device Name',max_length=100)
    iPort = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Port')
    iSlave = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Slave ID')
    sIP = models.GenericIPAddressField(verbose_name='IP Address')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TModbusDevice'
```

form:

```
class ModbusRegistersForm(ModelForm):
    ixRegisterType = ModelChoiceField(queryset=RegisterType.objects.all()),
    bRange = BooleanField(required=False)
    bRange.widget.attrs['data-form'] = 0
    class Meta:
        model = Register
        fields = ['sRegisterName','iStartingAddr','bRange','ixRegisterType','iOffset']
        widgets = {
                'sRegisterName': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Register Name','class': 'form-control', 'data-form': '0'}),
                'iStartingAddr': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Starting address','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0'}),
                'iOffset': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address offset','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0'}),
            }


class CreateModbusForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModbusDevice
        fields = ['sModbusName','iPort', 'iSlave', 'sIP']
        widgets = {
                'sModbusName': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Device Name','class': 'form-control','id': 'device-name',}),
                'iPort': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Port','class': 'form-control','id': 'port',}),
                'iSlave': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Slave id','class': 'form-control','id': 'slave-id',}),
                'sIP': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Modbus IP address','class': 'form-control','id': 'ip-address',})
            }
```

Comment: I think that's the default action for formsets. The reason why formsets always show all entries you previously saved is because user might want to edit the old data, or they simply want to delete them. You might need something else if you only care about adding entries.

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry I missed something, but you are not passing existing data as a queryset to the formset, which shouldn't show existing entries in the formset. Is that the exact view you have?

Comment: that is the exact code i have for my view. I'm only passing `RegisterTypes` because i need those to populate the dropdown

Comment: Just wondering why you're using formsets if you only ever want the one row at the bottom?

Comment: because I need it to be dynamic. It should start with 1 form but the user can click on "add row" which will append a form to the list and they can add as many as they want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to work
[django modelformset_factory sustains the previously submitted data even after successfully created the objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472751/django-modelformset-factory-sustains-the-previously-submitted-data-even-after-su)

seems i just have to prevent it from querying my tables